# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\base\LoginUsuario.php on line 13

Tags: php, mysqli

ayuda por favor hasta ahora comienzo en esto de php y pues tengo errores como cualquiera ,mi pregunta es,¿por que me da este error?, en el siguiente código.

```
<?php
  $alert = ''; 
  if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave']))
    {
        $alert = 'ingrese su usuario o su clave ';
    }else{
        require_once "conexion.php";
        $user = $_POST['usuario'];
        $pass = $_POST['clave'];

        $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE id_usuario='$user' AND contraseña='$pass'");
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($result > 0 ) 
        {
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['active']= true;
            $_SESSION['idUser']= $data['id_usuario'];
            header('location: sistema/');
        }else{
            $alert = 'El usuario o clave son incorrectos';
            sessi`introducir el código aquí`on_destroy();
        }

    }
}
?>
/*por acá esta la conexión.*/
<?php 

   $host = 'localhost';
   $user = 'root';
   $pass = '';
   $db = 'bdconlog';

   $conection = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
   if ($conection) {
    echo "error en la conexión";
   }
 ?>
```

espero puedan ayudarme, porque nose el error y eso incomoda a la hora de programar gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora bien, el error se ocasiona por que el parámetro que le estas pasando a la función `mysqli_num_rows` no cumple con lo esperado, por eso el error.

Solución.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE id_usuario='$user' AND contraseña='$pass'");

if(!$result){
  echo mysqli_error($conexion);
}
```

Con este simple `IF` obtendrás la razón del porque no se ejecuta la función siguiente. Puede que las columnas que están en tu tabla no existan o que se llamen de forma distinta, o que no soporte la `ñ` y debas encerrarla entre comillas, etc.

Saludos!